# HTTPS Only vs Redirect to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, https, redirect

When configuring AWS CloudFront (or Load Balancer) I have the option to choose to **Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS** or use **HTTPS Only** option.

My website works only with HTTPs, so I don't want any HTTP communication.

What difference does these options make to my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"HTTPS Only" means if someone goes to `http://foo.cloudfront.net/`, they'll get an error.

"Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS" means they'll get redirected from `http://foo.cloudfront.net/` to `https://foo.cloudfront.net/`.

"HTTPS Only" is fine for a CloudFront URL your users wouldn't type (like for an images CDN, or proxied in front of an API), but if you're using it to host the user-facing URLs, you want the redirects so someone who types your `www.example.com` still winds up on the site.